# Clarify my doubts in testng extend report

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

```
 @Test(priority = 0)
public void verify_Templete_BG(){
    logger =report.startTest("Verify TempleteBG");
    String expectedBG = "White";
    for(int pageNo = 1; pageNo<=3 ; pageNo++){
        Assert.assertTrue(expectedBG.equals("White"));
    }
    System.out.println("TC1 Pass");
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "TC1 Pass");
}
```

In this above sample program, I have some doubts.

1. If loop 2 fails(loop 1 and loop 3 pass) what will be output. Whether this testcase pass or fail.
2. If loop 3 fails(loop 1 and loop 2 pass) what will be output. Whether this testcase pass or fail.
3. Or else, how to know which loop got fails.

Comment: Case 1: If it fails in loop 2, the test case fails and stops immediately. It wont even run the 3rd loop. Same with case 2. For case 3: For assert.assertTrue(), I think you can have another parameter, give some message there. For example: `Assert.assertTrue(your condition, "Failed in loop - " + pageno);`. Please check the syntax, I use C# so have no idea about the syntax in Java

Answer (score 0):

If any assert fails, the test case will fail immediately.

You can add a little code and test out the different outcomes for yourself. Adjust the `actualBG` values for the different loops to be whatever you want. The code below is set up for Case 1, to fail on loop 2.

```
@Test(priority = 0)
public void verify_Templete_BG()
{
    logger = report.startTest("Verify TempleteBG");
    String expectedBG = "White";
    String actualBG = "";
    for (int pageNo = 1; pageNo <= 3; pageNo++)
    {
        switch (pageNo)
        {
            case 1:
                actualBG = "White";
                break;
            case 2:
                actualBG = "Black";
                break;
            case 3:
                actualBG = "White";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(expectedBG.equals(actualBG));
    }
    System.out.println("TC1 Pass");
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "TC1 Pass");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming yours is an Extent Reports. Extent reports actually prints step wise results for each Test cases. So you could actually modify it to like the below.

```
@Test(priority = 0)
public void verify_Templete_BG(){
    logger =report.startTest("Verify TempleteBG");
    String expectedBG = "White";
    for(int pageNo = 1; pageNo<=3 ; pageNo++){
       if(Assert.assertTrue(expectedBG.equals("White")))
          logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, pageNo +" Loop Passed");
       else
          logger.log(LogStatus.Fail, pageNo +" Loop Failed");
     }  
     report.endTest(logger);
     report.flush();
 }
```

assertTrue will return true or false based on the condition you are passing in. When it is true, you will print PageNo - Loop is passed. Else you will print it as failed.